# dual monitor with uvesafb / Intel 945GME?

Tags: graphics, framebuffer, intel-graphics

I'm using `uvesafb` to get a simple framebuffer on a Intel 945GME embedded graphics controller. That works fine.

The PC has a single combined DVI+VGA output connector and both outputs currently show the same graphics.

AFAIK that controller should be able to show different screens on the two outputs (ie. dual monitor setup). How can I configure `uvesafb` to operate in this mode?

Ideally I'd get a `/dev/fb1` along with `/dev/fb0`, but it would be also okay if the second screen whould just show a different offset within `/dev/fb0`.

Comment: Uvesafb works with vesa, and afaik there is nothing in the vesa standard about multiple monitors. If the driver wanted to set it up, it should have to communicate with the video chip on a non-vesa way (i.e. not through the vesa bios calls). But it would be a highly hardware-specific thing, and the driver doesn't know anything from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple: it is not possible with `uvesafb` as [it was not tailored for that purpose](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/fb/uvesafb.txt).

Xorg uses XrandR and recent multiple monitor configurations use Kernel Mode Setting (KMS), which recent video drivers are designed to use as well. You might therefore have better chances with KMS and an Intel 945GME. I have not checked however.

Comment: Well, `uvesafb` at least has support for Y-panning (`ypan`) and the generic framebuffer structs seem to know about "screens", so maybe I can set the second screen to a different Y pan position (exactly at the end of the first screen), so that can draw to both screens independently. I'll try to write a test program for that to verify.

Comment: As far as I know `ypan` is about vertical console scrolling on the same display. It's not intended for multiple displays for a tty.

Comment: This is not for a tty. I'm writing directly to the framebuffer memory. In theory, I could draw the second screen "below" the other (starting after the last pixel offset of the first screen) and set `ypan` for the second screen only. But apparently you're right, I can't find a way setting `ypan` for a single screen only - the generic framebuffer interface (not just `uvesafb`) doesn't seem to have the concept of a "screen" (despite some structs being named "*`SCREEN_INFO`").

Comment: That really is too bad but somehow expected as `uvesafb` is rather old, I think it pre-dates kernel mode settings development. So what about using the latter?

Comment: AFAIK the **basic** `/dev/fb` interface (the universal `ioctl` calls common to all drivers) itself doesn't offer any multi-screen support, hence `uvesafb` doesn't either. Perhaps more specific drivers come with proprietary extensions - I don't know. KMS is completely new to me, but looks promising. Will try to learn more about it... ;-)

Comment: Dissecting `xrandr` though intended for Xorg might be a good start.

Comment: Just out of pure luck I came across [this article](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Framebuffer-HOWTO/#AEN134), pretty old but it might undo everything I said above!

Comment: Are you referring to chapter 11? I can't find anything relevant in there, but I might be missing something!

Comment: No, I refer to the `video:map` part in chapter 3: «*video=map:01 will map VC0 to FB0, VC1 to FB1, VC2 to FB0, VC3 to FB1...*»

Comment: Ah, ok. That's when you have multiple framebuffers (multiple graphics cards),  but in my case there is only one fb device.

Comment: Crap! I didn't get it that way, I understand why. The documentation is not clear: «It represents the frame buffer of *some* video hardware[...]» Had it stated «There can be only one framebuffer device per  video card» it would have been obvious. So in the end the only option is to hack kernel mode setting, like I suspected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about `uvesafb` but I usually use `xrandr` to use dual monitor. In shell you can type:

```
xrandr
```

This will list all output possibilities. In my case, it shows the following:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2732 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 256mm x 144mm
1366x768       60.0*+
1360x768       59.8     60.0  
1024x768       60.0  
800x600        60.3     56.2  
640x480        59.9  
VGA1 connected 1366x768+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 230mm
1366x768       59.8*+
1024x768       75.1     75.0     60.0  
832x624        74.6  
800x600        75.0     60.3     56.2  
640x480        75.0     60.0  
720x400        70.1  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Then in order to make dual monitor, simply just type:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --right-of eDP1
```

to produce the same output

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --same-as eDP1
```

You can look more options at `man xrandr`

Comment: The OP wants to use multiple monitors in a frame buffer console so Xorg is off-topic here.